# Как сделать такой же массив php Laravel

Tags: php, массивы, laravel

У меня есть корзина с основной логикой в кастомном классе:

```
public $items = NULL;
    public $totalQty = 0;
    public $totalPrice = 0;

    public function __construct($oldCart){
      if($oldCart){
        $this->items = $oldCart->items;
        $this->totalQty = $oldCart->totalQty;
        $this->totalPrice = $oldCart->totalPrice;
      }
    }
    public function add($item, $id){
      $storedItem = [
        'qty' => 0,
        'id' => $item->id,
        'prod_url' => $item->url,
        'code_cat' => $item->category->code,
        'url_cat' => $item->category->url,
        'name' => $item->name,
        'cost' => $item->price,
        'price' => $item->price,
        'img' => $item->cardImage->path
      ];
      if($this->items){
        if(array_key_exists($id, $this->items)){
          $storedItem = $this->items[$id];
        }
      }
        $storedItem['qty']++;
        $storedItem['cost'] = $item->price * $storedItem['qty'];
        $this->items[$id] = $storedItem;
        $this->totalQty++;
        $this->totalPrice += $item->price;
    }
```

Чтобы разместить заказ в БД, я сериализую массив с товарами и размещаю эту строку в одном поле `cart`.

```
public function new_order_place(Request $request){

    $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);

    $order = new Order();
    $order->cart = serialize($cart);

      $order->name = $request->input('name')?$request->input('name'):Auth::user()->name;
      $order->email = $request->input('e-mail') ? $request->input('e-mail'):Auth::user()->email;
      $order->phone = $request->input('phone')?$request->input('phone'):(Auth::user()->phone?Auth::user()->phone:$this->validate($request, ['phone' => 'required']));
      $order->address = $request->input('address');

    Auth::check()?Auth::user()->orders()->save($order):$order->save();
    Session::forget('cart');
    return redirect()->route('index');
  }
```

Сам массив выглядит так:

```
__PHP_Incomplete_Class Object
(
    [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => App\Classes\Cart
    [items] => Array
        (
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [qty] => 1
                    [id] => 4
                    [prod_url] => gorenje_g_5111_wf
                    [code_cat] => large-home-appliances
                    [url_cat] => cookers
                    [name] => Плита газовая GORENJE G 5111 WF
                    [cost] => 490
                    [price] => 490
                    [img] => img_16.jpg
                )

        )

    [totalQty] => 1
    [totalPrice] => 490
)
```

Но так же у меня есть модальное окно, где пользователь может купить конкретный товар без добавления в корзину. Массив с товарами я делаю вручную и все размещаю в той же таблице в БД. Так как структура у массивов разная, я не могу отобразить товары в личном кабинете пользователя, именно поэтому мне нужно понять как сделать точно такую же структуру.

```
public function modal_order_place(Request $request){


    $selprod['items'] = array(
      $request->id => array(
          'name' => $request->name,
          'qty' => $request->qty,
          'code' => $request->code,
          'img' => $request->img,
          'totalPrice' => $request->totalPrice
        )
      );


    $order = new Order();

    $order->cart = serialize($selprod);

    $order->name = $request->username;
    $order->email = $request->email;
    $order->phone = $request->phone;

    Auth::check()?Auth::user()->orders()->save($order):$order->save();

    return response()->json([
      'notif_text' => 'Your order has been accepted for processing! Expect a call!'
    ]);
  }
```

У меня получилось так, но видно все равно не одно и тоже:

```
Array
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Стиральная машина LG F2T3HS6W
                    [qty] => 1
                    [code] => /large-home-appliances/washing-machines/lg_f2t3hs6w
                    [img] => /img/products/img_10.jpg
                )

            [totalPrice] => 380
        )

)
```

Laravel ругается:
`Trying to get property 'items' of non-object`
Если же удалю товар добавленный через модальное окно, то все уже работает. Проблема именно в массиве.

Есть у кого то идеи как это можно реализовать?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В методе `modal_order_place` вместо этого `$selprod['items'] = array( ...`  почему бы создать модель `Cart` и передать в модель `Order`

Другой вопрос, если это Лара, то, наверное, это всё контроллер.
А почему не создать некий сервис, который будет работать с корзиной, с заказами и тд?

Comment: Я беру массив, сериализую и полученную строку передаю в модель Order (а она в свою очередь в таблицу orders). Что вы имеете ввиду под сервисом? Я сделал так: пользователь делает заказ, у него в личном кабинете отображаются его заказы, а у админа отображаются все заказы. Админ отмечает обработанные заказы, а с необработанными работает и т.д. А что делает описанный вами сервис?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение. Дабы убрать эту проблему нужно перед сериализацией нашего массива преобразовать его в объект. Из моего кода:

```
public function modal_order_place(Request $request){
    $selprod['items'] = array(
      $request->id => array(
          'name' => $request->name,
          'qty' => $request->qty,
          'code' => $request->code,
          'img' => $request->img,
          'totalPrice' => $request->totalPrice
        )
      );

    $object = (object)$selprod;//Вот эта строка преобразует наш массив в объект

    $order = new Order();

    $order->cart = serialize($object);//Здесь уже сериализуем наш объект, а не массив

    $order->name = $request->username;
    $order->email = $request->email;
    $order->phone = $request->phone;

    Auth::check()?Auth::user()->orders()->save($order):$order->save();

    return response()->json([
      'notif_text' => 'Your order has been accepted for processing! Expect a call!'
    ]);
  }
```

При десериализации получается такой же по структуре массив, как и создает корзина и Laravel больше не ругается:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => name
                    [qty] => 1
                    [img] => img_10.jpg
                    [cost] => 380
                )

        )

)
```